set Custom font for all Controls on Resources in C#
I want to use a custom font for my WindowsForm.
For this purpose, I added the font to the program as follows.

And I used the following code to change the font of all the controls.
public void SetFontControls()
{
    var privatefontcollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    var fontLength = Properties.Resources.IRANSans.Length;
    var fontData = Properties.Resources.IRANSans;
    var data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);
    Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, data, fontLength);
    privatefontcollection.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);

    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        c.Font = new Font(privatefontcollection.Families[0], 12);
    }
}

I called this code in the Function load Form.
private void FormHydro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetFontControls();
}

But the problem is that the size changes all Controls but the font does not change.
I tried different fonts but nothing changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74179640/14171304
